# Abbreviations override in comments and quoted text

Tags: vim

I have the following handy abbreviation in VIM:

```
iab for for<Space>(<Space>{{<Esc>kA<Left><Left><Left><Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>
```

This nicely replaces `for` with the following text:

```
for (  ) {

}
```

However, I would like this abbreviation to work only in code, not in comments or in single- or double- quoted strings. How might this constraint be accomplished? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your abbreviation doesn't insert what you say it does in your example; it behaves rather oddly for me even though I do have Eatchar() defined.  My best guess is that it's triggering other abbreviations/mappings, and I will assume I should leave it alone.

My solution is to tie into the syntax engine, which means it will *only* work if you have syntax highlighting enabled.  Try this:

```
iab <buffer> <expr> for <SID>CodeInsert("for", "for<Space>(<Space>{{<Esc>kA<Left><Left><Left><Left><C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<CR>")

function! s:CodeInsert(abbr,str)
    let syn = synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line('.'), col('.') - 1, 1)), 'name')
    if syn ==? 'comment' || syn ==? 'constant'
        return a:abbr
    else
        return a:str
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you! I will play around with this solution and see what I can get working.

Comment: You are right, I have other imappings as well, such as `{{`. In any case, your solution works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to read about `synIDattr` and the other bits in the help, but when reading the help page `h ==?` it looks like I was getting the help text for `==`. What is the `==?` operator? Thanks.

Comment: See :help expr-==? (or :help expr4)

Comment: Hi, please excuse the late question. Why is the function name preceded with `s:`? I'm just trying to learn from the gurus. Thanks.

Comment: See `:help script-local`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `autocmd` to prevent the abbreviation from working in Python files:

```
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd FileType php,c,java iab for for<Space>...<CR>
endif
```

I don't think it's possible to prevent it from working just inside particular text section like double or single quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks. The Python bit is very secondary, I've removed it from the question as I see that it is distracting from the real issue. In any case I've upvoted. Thanks.